# EXECUTE AS USER = 'dbo' Throws error. Why?

Tags: sql-server

When I create a new database and I execute `SELECT user` it returns me that the user is `dbo`.

So I was creating a new user and executing the code as that user created. But when trying to change it again to `dbo`, it throws me an error that it doesn't exist, but I can see it. Why does this happens? I'm executing something wrong?

```
CREATE USER TestUser WITHOUT LOGIN
SELECT  user --Returns dbo
SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals --I can see both, dbo and TestUser and some other users of the system
EXECUTE AS user = 'TestUser'
SELECT  user --Returns TestUser
EXECUTE AS user = 'dbo'; -- Says that it doesn't exist
```

Error that throws:

> Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "dbo"
>   does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you
>   do not have permission.

Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio    14.0.17119.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because "you do not have permission". *Everything* after `EXECUTE AS` is done as the new user, including attempting to impersonate new users, and `TestUser`, not being a sysadmin, cannot impersonate `dbo`. `REVERT` instead.

Comment: Yeah, that make sense. Thought as the database owner you could change again. I guess if the user is admin, or have more permission it could access to the user 'dbo'

Comment: Yes -- if you did `ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER TestUser`, then `TestUser` could impersonate `dbo`. However, there's little to no point in this, because obviously `TestUser` would already be able to do everything `dbo` can. `EXECUTE AS USER = 'dbo'` is not very practical (a stored procedure with `EXECUTE AS OWNER` is another matter).

Answer (score 1):

The key is in the error message "this type of principal cannot be impersonated". Basically, user 'dbo' should be considered an alias or a role (database owner). So, when you create a database/table/etc by using your login you have the database owner privilege. For example, if you log in as user 'sa' and create a table, the full qualified table name is DataBaseName.dbo.TableName.

Why would you need to execute as 'dbo'? It would be better not to assign database owner rights to a bunch of users, but rather keep the users/roles/permissions well compartmented.

Comment: You're right, that *would* be better, but all that notwithstanding, `dbo` is a principal that *can* be impersonated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @PatrickD I was just wondering why it wasn't working, and wanted to have an answer.

Comment: @JeroenMostert yes, you're correct - your answer is more accurate